# Reduce speed of smooth scroll in scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview, smooth-scrolling

I have a scroll View. I performed smooth-scroll.using smoothScrollBy().It all works fine, but I want to change the duration of the smooth-scroll. Smooth-scroll happens very fast and user is not understanding what happened.Please help me reduce smooth-scroll speed?

Answer (score 188):

The simple answer is just to replace

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollTo);
```

with

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY",  scrollTo).setDuration(duration).start();
```

where `duration` is the time in milliseconds you want it to take.

Comment: What is ObjectAnimator? Where should this code be called?

Comment: This definitely works. But for my case it where I trig the smoothScroll `onTouch` `ACTION_UP`, it was kind of buggy, flicking.

Comment: How can we achieve the same thing with `RecyclerView`? I've tried its `scrollY` and `verticalScrollbarPosition` but they won't work.

Answer (score 14):

Try the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    ValueAnimator realSmoothScrollAnimation = 
        ValueAnimator.ofInt(parentScrollView.getScrollY(), targetScrollY);
    realSmoothScrollAnimation.setDuration(500);
    realSmoothScrollAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            int scrollTo = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            parentScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollTo);
        }
    });

    realSmoothScrollAnimation.start();
}
else
{
    parentScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, targetScrollY);
}
```

Comment: This should be selected as answer to the question. +1

Comment: Instead of using ValueAnimator, why not use ObjectAnimator (a subclass of ValueAnimator)? It makes it even easier - a one liner, in fact: ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY", targetScrollY).setDuration(500).start();

Answer (score 4):

This is how I achieved a smooth vertical scroll (like movie credits).  This also allows the user to move the scroll up and down and allow it to continue scrolling when they let go.  In my XML, I encapsulated my TextView inside of a ScrollView called "scrollView1".  Enjoy!

```
    final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lyrics);
    final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0,5);         // 5 is how many pixels you want it to scroll vertically by
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);     // 10 is how many milliseconds you want this thread to run
        }
    };

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How will I know that scroll reached the bottom and the runnable has to be turned off? How to handle this?

Answer (score -2):

```
whichScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getBase().getDocumentModel().getPageCount()-1));
mNextScreen = whichScreen;
final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
final int delta = newX - getScrollX();
//scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, Math.abs(delta) * 2);
scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, Math.abs(delta));
invalidate();
```