# Can I control scrollview speed on while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am using a ScrollView in a layout and I need to control speed of scrolling in scrollview.already use manythings.like a object animator ,timer but those are doesn't help me.then how can i control (or) set limited speed on scrolling in scrollview on android.

Comment: Here this question already been asked like [Reduce speed of smooth scroll in scroll view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642677/reduce-speed-of-smooth-scroll-in-scroll-view), are you asking for the same?

Comment: but that's not a proper solution for my question.above link answer work on "Autoscroll" not control the speed of scroll.i already try this.it not working to control the speed...when user scroll...

Answer (score 0):

This works for `ViewPager`, Never tried for `ScrollView`

```
public class FixedSpeedScroller extends OverScroller {

    private int mDuration = 2000;

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
        super(context, interpolator);
    }


    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy) {
        // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
    }

    public void setFixedDuration(int duration) {
        this.mDuration = duration;
    }
}
```

How to use -

```
try {
   Field _mScroller = ScrollView.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
   _mScroller.setAccessible(true);
   FixedSpeedScroller scroller = new FixedSpeedScroller(mPager.getContext(), new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
   scroller.setFixedDuration(600);
   _mScroller.set(mScrollView, scroller);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Scroller exception"  +e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Not a good practice. just use above code, let me know what happens, Is firing an exception or what?

Answer (score 0):

**How to control Android ListView scrolling speed**

You can control the scrolling speed of an Android ListView using code like this in a Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // scroll speed decreases as friction increases. a value of 2 worked
    // well in an emulator; you need to test it on a real device
    getListView().setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 2);
}
```

Default ListView scroll speed is too fast by default, and as a result, it’s hard on the eyes when you scroll through a lot of items